# yap suddenly fails to print .dvi-Files

Tags: miktex2.9, dvi, yap

yap suddenly fails to print .dvi-Files, instead displays message "MiKTeX encountered an internal error", although MiKTeX installed October 2020 hasn't been changed/updated since. (The pertaining info indicates "Line 349".)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear currently. Are the dvi files the same, i.e., do you have a file that used to print but now the same file does not print, or is the file new? If the file is new, what is the LaTeX code that produces the dvi file? Is this about physical printing on paper? Does Yap show the file correctly on the screen and is the problem just the printing, or is the file also not shown at all or not shown correctly? Can you print when you convert the dvi file to ps or pdf and print the converted file?

Comment: Files that used to print (up to March 9) don't now (from March 12 onwards). I tried to print on my HP LaserJet. The dvi-files show correctly on the screen. But there were automatic MS updates to my Windows 10 system in between the above dates. Could this affect the performance of my local MiKTeX implementation?

Comment: PS.: The same source converted to pdf prints.

Comment: And does `File-Print Postscript...` work?

Comment: No, " The MiKTeX print utility failed for some reason"